# Got LoaderExceptions in setting specflow 1.9 in for WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone-7, nuget, specflow, wp7test

I tried to follow
https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/wiki/Setting-up-a-new-BDD-machine

to setup Specflow on WindowsPhone.

I had a Specflow 1.8.1 installed. so I uninstall 1.8.1 first and install Specflow 1.9 plugin on VS2010. 
When running the Specflow. I still got following exception.

[ERROR] Add two numbers: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
  System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
     at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.Discovery.RuntimeBindingRegistryBuilder.BuildBindingsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.Initialize(Assembly[] bindingAssemblies)
     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.InitializeTestRunner(Assembly[] bindingAssemblies)
     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestRunnerFactory.Create(Assembly testAssembly)
     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.CreateTestRunner(TestRunnerKey key)
     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner(TestRunnerKey key)
     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner(Assembly testAssembly, Boolean async)
     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner()
     at ClassLibrary1.SpecFlowFeature1Feature.FeatureSetup() in C:\source\PhoneApp1\ClassLibrary1\SpecFlowFeature1.feature.cs:line 0
     at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(TestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1ace6ed01d0a43bb\TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework\TaskExecutors\StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.cs:line 40
     at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(TestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1ace6ed01d0a43bb\TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework\TaskExecutors\StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.cs:line 21
     at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.ChainedTaskExecutor.Execute(TestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1ace6ed01d0a43bb\TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework\TaskExecutors\ChainedTaskExecutor.cs:line 20
     at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThreadExecutor.ExecuteTestNodeTask(TestNode testNode, ITaskExecutor task, TraceEventType eventType) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\1ace6ed01d0a43bb\TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework\TestThreadExecutor.cs:line 220

The internal exception is LoaderExceptions include
{"Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41"}

I don't know why it still load 1.8.1 SpecFlow assembly. I have uninstalled the SpecFlow 1.8.1. Is there any other place I need to change manually?

Thanks!

Comment: When I replaced the 1.9 specflow library with 1.8. But it shows 1.9 library not found now. Still blocked by this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WP7Test package seems to have a dependency to SpecFlow 1.8.1. As far as i see on the github project, it has not been updated yet to SpecFlow 1.9.

SpecRun.SpecFlow 1.1 requires SpecFlow 1.9. (This will be used if you install the obsolete SpecRun (1.0) package.)

I think the best would be to fork the WP7Test project on github and update it to use SpecFlow 1.9. After doing this it should also work fine with the latest SpecRun.

(An alternative way would be to use SpecRun.SpecFlow 1.0 package that works with SpecFlow 1.8.1 and also supported by the SpecFlow 1.9 IDE integration.)